# HTML Trying to load images and videos

Tags: javascript, html

I am a student studying computer programming. Chrome and Firefox are not loading my video or audio.

```
<p> 
<audio controls>
  <source src="Piano.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</p>

<p>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Son.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</p>
```

Comment: did you provide the correct source path?

Comment: please explain further maybe thats where the problem is, i have saved them in a folder in my desktop.

Comment: Should i import them to the eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put Son.mp4 and Piano.mp3 at the same folder as the html

Comment: Hey what about the applet i need to put in there too?

Comment: Yes, just put it in the same folder